# pyqt and requests: Load an image into GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, python-requests, qimage

All my images are saved into a directory

pictures = '/x.com/user37/Public/....../images/'

I'm trying to load images from that directory onto my GUI screen. This is what I have in my `__init__` method.

```
self.movieimg = QImage()
self.imagelbl = QLabel()
self.imagelbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
self.imagelbl.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.movieimg))
```

When I include, after initializing a QGridLayout

```
layout.addWidget(self.movieimg, 1, 1)
```

I get an error saying that **argument 1 in `addWidget` is an invalid type**. Why is this the case?

I created a dictionary entry = { } and I have another function where I call requests

```
def nextEntry(self)
    r= requests.get(self.MOVIES_URL + str(mid))
    resp = json.loads(r.content)
    img = resp['movie_id']

    self.movieimg = QImage(self.movie['img'])
    self.imglbl.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.movieimg))
```

Thoughts? Do I need to directly call this function before that statement in the main `__init__` function? Thank you!

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting, it contributes to clarity of problem statement. You can check formatting by looking at the preview section below your answer and fixing before clicking "Post your question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.movieimg` is `QImage()` type and you need to pass `QWidget` type as first argument to `addWidget` method. `QLabel()` inherits from `QWidget`, so try to passing `self.imagelbl` instead.